# Multithreading PHP Function

Tags: php, multithreading, laravel, laravel-5

Currently when I execute this function with say 60 URL's I get a HTTP 504 error. Is there anyway to multithread this so that I no longer get a 504 error and iterate throughout the entire list of URL's?

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function parse()
    {
        $input = Request::all();
        $csv = $input['laraCsv'];
        $new_csv = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ',', $csv));

        $headerInfo = [];
        //$titles = [];
        $csvArray = str_getcsv($new_csv, ",");
        $csvLength = count($csvArray);
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $csvLength) {

            if(strpos($csvArray[$i], '.pdf') !== false) {
                print_r($csvArray[$i]);
            }
            else{
                array_push($headerInfo, get_headers($csvArray[$i], 1));
            }
            //sleep(3);
            //echo file_get_contents($csvArray[$i]);
            $i++;
        }
        return view('csvViewer')->with('data', $headerInfo)->with('urls', $csvArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: All that would do is give you a 504 faster

Comment: @rjdown What would you suggest I do?

Comment: Have you already taken a look at [`curl_multi`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)?

Comment: I have not, would this be a better alternative?

Comment: 504 is usually caused by hammering the server. So just cut back a bit on the time between requests.

Comment: @rjdown I tried to sleep() for 3 seconds before each increment, but no dice

Comment: Wait are you getting 504 from your server or from the `get_headers`?

Comment: @DaveChen "504 Gateway Time-out

nginx/1.8.0"

Comment: And that's within $headerInfo? Or is it coming from your digital ocean website?

Comment: @DaveChen Coming from my Digital Ocean website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used digitalocean in the past before but I'm not sure what error codes they give if you run out of time, (also `set_time_limit(0);` should already be in your code).

See if this works:

```
<?php

function getHeaders($data) {
  $curly = array();
  $result = array();

  $mh = curl_multi_init();

  foreach ($data as $id => $url) {
      $curly[$id] = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
      curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
      curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
  }

  $running = null;
  do {
      curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  } while ($running > 0);

  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
      $result[$id] = array_filter(explode("\n", curl_multi_getcontent($c)));
      curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }

  curl_multi_close($mh);
  return $result;
}

$urls = array(
  'http://google.com',
  'http://yahoo.com',
  'http://doesnotexistwillitplease.com'
);

$r = getHeaders($urls);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($r);
```

So once you've gotten all your URLs into an array, run it like `getHeaders($urls);`.

If it doesn't work try it only with 3 or 4 urls first. Also `set_time_limit(0);` at the top as mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is because of your code ? it could also be the server configuration.

about HTTP 504

> This problem is entirely due to slow IP communication between back-end
>   computers, possibly including the Web server. Only the people who set
>   up the network at the site which hosts the Web server can fix this
>   problem.

Comment: The server is a 1gb digital ocean server that was created through laravel forge